# How can instantiate Class<T> from T?

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I've got following method:

```
public <T> execute(HttpRequest request) {
   ...
   // in parseAs i have to pass Class<T> how can I instantiate it from T?
   request.execute().parseAs(classT);
}
```

PS: parseAs is method from [google http client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/google-http-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponse.java).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot with those parameters.

Java's generics use something called type erasure - basically all those `T`s become `Object` at runtime. So if you actually need to know what class this `T` is, you'll need a `Class` object to be passed in. This is exactly what `parseAs` is doing - to invoke `parseAs<String>`, you'd call `parseAs(String.class)`.

However, your `execute` has no `Class` parameter. As such, it has no idea what specialization it was invoked with, and cannot therefore pass that data on to `parseAs`.

The solution is to add a `Class<T>` parameter and punt to the next level up in the call chain, where the concrete type is (hopefully) known:

```
public <T> execute(Class<T> klass, HttpRequest request) {
   ...
   request.execute().parseAs(klass);
}
```

Comment: Though note this only works if T is not itself a parameterized type. It can be Integer but not List<Integer>, for example. (The code will compile just fine, but there's no way to get a value of type Class<List<Integer>> so it won't be useful.)

Comment: What about this public void execute(HttpRequest request, AjaxListener<T> callback) still impossible without additional class variable?

Comment: @skayred, nope! The `<T>` vanishes at runtime, and it becomes `execute(HttpRequest request, AjaxListener callback)`

Comment: @skayred, it should also be noted that some other languages avoid this problem - notably, .NET (C# etc) and C++ do _not_ perform type erasure. Java does this because it needed to remain compatible with libraries built before generics were introduced.

Comment: @skayred, also, `execute(HttpRequest request, AjaxListener<T> callback, Class<T> klass)` would make it possible.

Comment: Yep, I know that C# provide a better support of generics